# Android : How to hide Navigation bar and Optionmenu in login fragment?

Tags: android

I have an activity and  3 fragments, the fragment I display is login Fragment.I want to hide the Navigation bar Floating action button and Option Menu in the Login Fragment and display in other two fragment. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using a view pager?

Comment: you can post the code to be able to get the best help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long research I found a solution. That is I lock the navigation drawer in the Login fragment using the code :

```
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)      getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

And again using the code below to unlock the navigation drawer in the Welcome fragment.

```
  DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)   getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
  drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNDEFINED);
```

This is same for Option Menu as well.